# Is there a way to get/set the list of selected ranges for a text box?

Tags: javascript, dom

In Firefox, (but not chrome apparently), I can create multiple selections within the same box by holding ctrl:

[image: multiple selections within a single box]

Is there a way to manipulate these selections using javascript? I see that there are `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`, but these properties only seem to apply to the last selection that was made.

Comment: Just a thought: I wonder if you could keep track of each selected portion in an array. In theory you could use the selectionStart value compared to the previous selectionEnd value on each update (which I guess would have to be a keyboard/mouse event) to determine if a new selection segment has been created. Like I said, just a thought.

Comment: As far as applying those selection segments later on, that will be an interesting challenge.

Comment: Actually I take that back, document.body.createTextRange() should make the second part fairly straightforward.